# EF Core select only needed columns with left join and group by

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to do Linq group by query with a left join count:

```
from region in context.Regions
join person in context.Persons on region.Id equals person.RegionId into persons
from personNullable in persons.DefaultIfEmpty()
group personNullable by region.Name into g
select new { g.Key, Members = g.Count(r => r != null) }
```

Result:

```
[Name], [Members]
AAA     0 
BBB     2
CCC     1
```

But this query translated to SQL without grouping and select all of the columns from both tables (which is not needed):

```
SELECT [region0].[ID], [region0].[DateChanged], [region0].[UsrIDChanged], [region0].[DateCreated], [region0].[UsrIDCreated], [region0].[IsDefault], [region0].[Name], [region0].[ParentRegionID], [person0].[ID], [person0].[Street], [person0].[LastName], [person0].[LastVisitDate], [person0].[Age], [person0].[Name], [person0].[RegionID]
FROM [Regions] AS [region0]
LEFT JOIN [Persons] AS [person0] ON [region0].[ID] = [person0].[RegionID]
ORDER BY [region0].[ID]
GO
```

Is this possible to select only needed columns or do a native group by query similar to this:

```
SELECT r.Name, COUNT(p.Id) AS Memebers 
FROM Region AS r
LEFT JOIN Person AS p ON r.Id = p.Region
GROUP BY r.Name
```

Comment: which version of ef core are you using? group by was always in memory until version 2.1: "Before version 2.1, in EF Core the GroupBy LINQ operator would always be evaluated in memory. We now support translating it to the SQL GROUP BY clause in most common cases." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1

Comment: I'm using EF Core 2.1.0 but it seems it still uses in-memory grouping in my case

Comment: I assume it's because of these restriction mentioned here:  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2341 and I assume it's because of point 5. "5. Using Key/Aggregate values after GroupBy in joins"